# What is the proper way to run tasks in succession in Gradle

Tags: gradle, task

I have a task like this in gradle: `task startServer (dependsOn: [':backend:appengineStop', ':backend:appengineRun'])`. The problem is appengineStop is not run or doesn't seem to be run before `appengineRun` runs.
 I am saying this because when the server is running and I execute this task, it should stop the server first (`appengineStop`) and start the server again (`appengineRun`), but this is not happening and build fails saying `"Port already in use"`.
That is why I listed appengineStop first so it will stop the server. Can someone please explain.

Comment: See [Ordering tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Setting of deppendsOn of your task just saying, that both tasks on wich you depends (it's `':backend:appengineStop'` and `':backend:appengineRun'` in your case) will be executed before your dependent `startServer` task.  The order of execution of this tasks is not determined. Probably, they'll be executed in alphabetical order, but it's a gradle implementation's behavior and you don't use to rely on it.

Gardle tasks have a capacity to determine their order using mustRunAfter method, which make a task running just after task specified as an argument is executed.

You can try to do it by adding to your build script somthing like:

```
task startServer (dependsOn: [':backend:appengineStop', ':backend:appengineRun']) {
    tasks.getByPath(':backend:appengineRun').mustRunAfter ':backend:appengineStop'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that n let you know.

Comment: Like you said, I tried running this: 

task startServer (dependsOn: ':backend:appengineRun') {
    tasks.getByPath(':backend:appengineRun').mustRunAfter ':backend:appengineStop'
}

and one line of importance in the output is:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
              
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineExplodeApp'.
> Unable to delete file C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AndroidStudioProjects\AppEngine\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.18.jar
              
I think the 'Unable to delete...' means the server is still running.

Comment: Edited my answer, to show you how it could be made. And had it now tested with my gradle version 2.6. The main thing, is not to change your dependsOn of startServer task.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav for the edit. Still getting the same output. The idea behine the task is: I want to check if the server is already running as executing appengineRun when the server is running would give error port occupied or similar; so I want to either stop the server and start the server again, or leave the server running so I can run integration tests. In other words, is there any way of knowing if the server is running within gradle task. Hope I have made things clear.

Comment: Could you check, whether those task are executed via console output? May be add some println  in order to to debug it.

Gradle is same as groovy, som you can make your task with java-like code, to check everything you need. For web server you can do it as: task check << {
    def url = "http://google.com"
    def content
    try {
        content = url.toURL().openConnection().with { conn ->
            readTimeout = 10000
            if( responseCode != 200 ) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
    catch( e ) {
        // do something
    }
}